# Древний и дерево

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Древний, древо — явно однокоренные слова. Но как они могут быть связаны по смыслу? Почему древность ассоциируется с деревом?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Считается, что прилагательное древний в значении "изготовленный из дерева" приобрело второе значение "давний" в о.-с. языке, в котором отмечено существование  наречия dreve - прежде,раньше, некогда, давно. В и.-е. языке было два корня deru (драть, дерево) и dreu (верный, крепкий, устойчивый, сравнить: true (англ) - правдивый). Значение "давний" возникло, возможно,  на пересечении этих значений - крепкий, давний, как дерево, как дуб. В то же время в этимологическом значении это не вполне ясное слово.

Answer (score 0):

«Почему древность ассоциируется с деревом?» Ассоциируется, но с трудом и точно не у всех. Трудно абстрагироваться от *древесины*, *деревянного* и всякой *д.в.п.*, —  надо уметь в красках и запахах представлять или наблюдать живой образец лет под тысячу, по крайней мере.

«Древний, древо — как они могут быть связаны по смыслу?» Могут. *Древо* воспринимается не столько растением, сколько существом, в котором мы находим себя при взгляде со стороны. То есть это — символ (и антропогенный объект) на основе образа плодоносного дерева с уходящими в древность корнями и кроной будущего времени.